# What is the rotational symmetry number used to calculate the rotational entropy from an ORCA frequency calculation?

Tags: computational-chemistry, software, symmetry

The quantum chemistry software ORCA gives the following warning on frequency calculations:

```
CAUTION: The rotational entropy is not quite correctly treated here
         because it includes a symmetry number that is not yet correctly
         implemented in ORCA!
For a nonlinear molecule the correct rotational entropy is:
    S(rot) = R*(ln(qrot/sn)+1.5)
    R    = 8.31441 J/mol/K = 1.987191683e-3 kcal/mol/K
    qrot = 4922043.1563766
    sn is the rotational symmetry number. We have assumed 3 here
       if it is different for your molecule then you should correct
       the printed rotational entropy by manually evaluating the equation
       as given above

For convenience we print out the resulting values for sn=1 - 12:
 sn= 1  qrot/sn= 4922043.1564 T*S(rot)=    10.02 kcal/mol T*S(tot)=    34.72 kcal/mol
 sn= 2  qrot/sn= 2461021.5782 T*S(rot)=     9.61 kcal/mol T*S(tot)=    34.31 kcal/mol
 sn= 3  qrot/sn= 1640681.0521 T*S(rot)=     9.37 kcal/mol T*S(tot)=    34.07 kcal/mol
 sn= 4  qrot/sn= 1230510.7891 T*S(rot)=     9.20 kcal/mol T*S(tot)=    33.90 kcal/mol
 sn= 5  qrot/sn=  984408.6313 T*S(rot)=     9.06 kcal/mol T*S(tot)=    33.77 kcal/mol
 sn= 6  qrot/sn=  820340.5261 T*S(rot)=     8.96 kcal/mol T*S(tot)=    33.66 kcal/mol
 sn= 7  qrot/sn=  703149.0223 T*S(rot)=     8.87 kcal/mol T*S(tot)=    33.57 kcal/mol
 sn= 8  qrot/sn=  615255.3945 T*S(rot)=     8.79 kcal/mol T*S(tot)=    33.49 kcal/mol
 sn= 9  qrot/sn=  546893.6840 T*S(rot)=     8.72 kcal/mol T*S(tot)=    33.42 kcal/mol
 sn=10  qrot/sn=  492204.3156 T*S(rot)=     8.65 kcal/mol T*S(tot)=    33.36 kcal/mol
 sn=11  qrot/sn=  447458.4688 T*S(rot)=     8.60 kcal/mol T*S(tot)=    33.30 kcal/mol
 sn=12  qrot/sn=  410170.2630 T*S(rot)=     8.55 kcal/mol T*S(tot)=    33.25 kcal/mol
```

Now, I have got the following two questions:

1. What is the rotational symmetry number $s_n$, i.e. how is it defined?
2. What symmetry number $s_n$ would a molecule with no symmetry, i.e. $C_1$ point group have? The way I understand it, the rotational symmetry number reflects the rotational symmetry, e.g. $\ce{CHCl3}$ would have $s_n=3$ as there are three equivalent structures superimposed by the $C_3$ symmetry element. So that my guess is that $s_n = 1$ in that case. Is that correct?

Comment: ad 1) The rotational symmetry number corrects for the fact that you have to take the Pauli principle into account when deriving the partition function. That is, it accounts for the spin statistical weights of the different rotational levels.

Comment: @Paul "It accounts for the spin statistical weights of the different rotational levels" is not a really clear definition to me, sorry. In what way does it do this and what does it have to do with the Pauli principle?

Comment: On the link provided in the answer below the symmetry number is defined as: "The "rotational symmetry number or external symmetry number [...] is the number of unique orientations of the rigid molecule that only interchange identical atoms." I think that's a pretty clear-cut definition.

Comment: @Paul So given the definition from my comment above, I really don't see the connection to the Pauli principle, maybe you can enlighten me, I never really gotten warm with statistical thermodynamics : )

Comment: In the case of molecular hydrogen there are two identical H nuclei and when constructing the partition function or any other statistical thermodynamic quantity, the indistinguishability of these should be taken into account (that is, exchange of identical particles should give $\pm$ in accordance with the generalized Pauli principle). We can construct 4 spin functions: 3 symmetric ones and one antisymmetric one. The symmetric ones combine with odd rotational states and the antisymmetric one with even states.

Comment: So that the overall wavefunction is antisymmetric for exchange of the two spin 1/2 nuclei. As a consequence there are 3 times as many molecules with odd rotational states as even ones and this should be taken into account into the degeneracy factors when summing over all energies. The same reasoning can be extended to more complex molecules having identical nuclei.

Comment: Ah, so - @Paul, are you essentially saying that treating all nuclei of the same atomic number as identical is not strictly correct in the case where the nuclear spin varies among them? If so, I think it would absolutely be worth writing it up into an answer.

Comment: @Paul OK, so in the case of $\mathsf{H_2}$, you end up with $s_n=2$. That is in contrast to the answer of hBy2Py and to 2) of my question. Hmm... Now that I look at it I also see that the definition provided by us at least runs into problems for linear molecules as then $s_n=\infty$, am I right? Or is then $s_n=1$ as it reduces to "basically one rotation".

Comment: Only for nonlinear molecules it is the case that the symmetry number is the order of the point group if only pure rotations (including E) are considered.  $s=1$ for linear molecules of $C_{\infty\text{v}}$ and $s=2$ for $D_{\infty\text{h}}$ symmetry.

Comment: @Paul I see, so it is actually the number of mappings between atoms that can be achieved by proper rotations, that makes sense...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your #2 is exactly right, as far as I know, which answers your #1.**

A key thing to remember is that the rotational symmetry number doesn't include reflections, so molecules in groups like $C_s$ still have $s_n = 1$ since there are no superimposable orientations achievable *only* with rotations.

For reference: Table II of the [NIST CCCBDB introduction to thermochemistry](http://cccbdb.nist.gov/thermo.asp) is a nice, concise summary of the symmetry numbers for the common point groups observed in chemistry.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply : ) The only thing I don't get then is why the ORCA people made $s_n=3$ the default setting, as obviously $s_n=1$ is by far the most common...

Comment: @ketbra Agreed, defaulting to $1$ would make more sense to me, too. Perhaps, though, the relative error associated with an incorrect $s_n$ is largest for small molecules, which have a much higher probability of $s_n > 1$, and thus they chose a compromise value.

Comment: I see. That makes sense : )